# AngularJS invalid label in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
  controller('MyCtrl1', [$scope, function($scope) {
    $scope.hello: "hello world";
  }])
```

I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid label
```

pointing to .hello. 
This is a pretty basic example from the angularjs docs but I dont get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use standard assignment as you are passing a function to controller and not an object.
Thus it should be

```
$scope.hello = "hello world";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have two options:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
  controller('MyCtrl1', function($scope) {
    $scope.hello = "hello world";
  });
```

If you don't use Google's Closure compiler, and:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
  controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.hello = "hello world";
  }]);
```

if you use it...

This string `'$scope'` is put in the array to verify that the `$scope` will be injected  because the minifier may rename this parameter and the reflection will no longer work as you expect.